# How to add another node in this Html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating one page where I need to create one custom timeline chart. I find something which is helpful but i'm unable to add another node.
Here's my code:

```css
.ps-timeline-sec {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container {
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol:before {
    background: #348e80;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px !important;
    left: 36px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol:after {
    background: #348e80;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit !important;
    left: 36px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline {
    margin: 130px 0 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #348e80;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 120px !important;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li {
    height: 220px;
    float: none !important;
    width: inherit !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:nth-child(2) .img-handler-bot img {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .img-handler-bot {
    bottom: 40px !important;
    width: 40% !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .img-handler-bot img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .ps-top {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    top: 20px;
    width: 50% !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span {
    left: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:before {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:before {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 150px !important;
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top img {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 80% !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 115px !important;
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li p {
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-top {
    width: 60% !important;
    float: right !important;
    right: 0;
    top: -40px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-bot {
    width: 60% !important;
    float: right !important;
    right: 0;
    top: -40px;
  }
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol:before {
  background: #348e80;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 49.5%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol:after {
  background: #348e80;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 49.5%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline {
  margin: 390px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #348e80;
  list-style: none;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #348e80;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px -10;
  color: #df8625;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:before {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:after {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 44%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:before {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:after {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 44%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-bot {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Horizontal Timeline Responsive</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section class="ps-timeline-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <ol class="ps-timeline">
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-top">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_03.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-bot">
          <p>Do you have a recent injury or long term pain?</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-top">01</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-bot">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_13.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-top">
          <p>Have you tried Physiotherapy, Chiropractor or your GP without the pain free results?</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-bot">02</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-top">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_05.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-bot">
          <p>Let Physology assess and treat your pain with our trusted revolusionary approach.</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-top">03</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-bot">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_10.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-top">
          <p>Join our happy family of pain free clients.</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-bot">04</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in that code I want to add another picture whose number should be 5 and some text next to that picture. while I try to add another li element it will collide with another existing li element.
like this picture
[image]

so How to achieve another node here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to duplicate the `<li>` element inside the `<ol>` list, then change the content. Be carefull of leaving the HTML structure intact.

EDIT:
You also need to adapt the `width` attribute in the `.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li` class in the way that fit the number of elements (example 4 items is 25%, as 100/4=25).
Also you need to adapt the classes of the inner elements with the wanted sequence (`bot-top-bot` or the inverse).

```css
.ps-timeline-sec {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container {
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol:before {
    background: #348e80;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px !important;
    left: 36px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol:after {
    background: #348e80;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit !important;
    left: 36px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline {
    margin: 130px 0 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #348e80;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 120px !important;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li {
    height: 220px;
    float: none !important;
    width: inherit !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:nth-child(2) .img-handler-bot img {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .img-handler-bot {
    bottom: 40px !important;
    width: 40% !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .img-handler-bot img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li:last-child .ps-top {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    top: 20px;
    width: 50% !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span {
    left: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:before {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:before {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 150px !important;
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top img {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 80% !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 115px !important;
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li p {
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-top {
    width: 60% !important;
    float: right !important;
    right: 0;
    top: -40px;
  }
  .ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-bot {
    width: 60% !important;
    float: right !important;
    right: 0;
    top: -40px;
  }
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol:before {
  background: #348e80;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 49.5%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol:after {
  background: #348e80;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 49.5%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline {
  margin: 390px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #348e80;
  list-style: none;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #348e80;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px -10;
  color: #df8625;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:before {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-top:after {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 44%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:before {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li span.ps-sp-bot:after {
  content: "";
  color: #348e80;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #348e80;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 44%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-top img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .img-handler-bot img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.ps-timeline-sec .container ol.ps-timeline li .ps-bot {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Horizontal Timeline Responsive</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section class="ps-timeline-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <ol class="ps-timeline">
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-top">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_03.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-bot">
          <p>Do you have a recent injury or long term pain?</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-top">01</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-bot">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_13.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-top">
          <p>Have you tried Physiotherapy, Chiropractor or your GP without the pain free results?</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-bot">02</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-top">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_05.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-bot">
          <p>Let Physology assess and treat your pain with our trusted revolusionary approach.</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-top">03</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="img-handler-bot">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_10.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-top">
          <p>Join our happy family of pain free clients.</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-bot">04</span>
      </li>
            <li>
        <div class="img-handler-top">
          <img src="http://www.physology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ps-elem_10.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-bot">
          <p>This is the fifth node</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ps-sp-top">05</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, @Greedo I tried your approach but in horizontal view it is coming distorted. I just updated my question there I attached the picture in horizontal view